# Why are the pixels distorted when I run a simple SFML code?

Tags: c++, graphics, sfml

I'm relatively new to sfml. The pixels get distorted, dont really know how to put it into words honestly, basically even displaying a simple circle or a rectangle distorts half the window into thin horizontal lines, I have an attachment of the output. This sometimes happens and sometimes don't, don't really have any idea why it is caused. I don't think it is a hardware issue because like I said, sometimes it works smoothly.

I am running this on wsl ubuntu 22.04.s LTS on windows 11.

The code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[The output I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JY34N.png)

Comment: could very easily be a driver issue, or a bug in WSL, or cosmic radiation hitting your CPU/GPU, try using a VM instead of WSL and see if the bug persists, usually hypervisors offer a choice of software simulated graphics drivers, so a faulty driver won't matter.

Comment: works fine on my machine